# Session management mysql and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using [passportjs](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) passport-local for authentication (username and password) in my web application.

#### Technology/Framework

Node.js

Expressjs

mysql

passportjs

#### Problem:

Session destroyed when server goes down. I need to implement a mechanism to persist session for logged in user. So that when server is up he can access the application without login process.

#### Note:

I cannot able to use redis for session management since we often **flushall** to clear caching data.

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Comment: You can pick another session store [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores).

Comment: Post your session config code

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented [express mysql session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var session = require('express-session')
var mysql_store = require('express-mysql-session')(session),
var db_connection = mysql.createPool({
   canRetry: true,
   database: 'database',
   host: 'host',
   user: 'user',
   password: 'password',
   connectionLimit: 100
});

var sessionStore = new mysql_store({
    expiration: 60 * 2000
}, db_connection);

app.use(session({
    secret: '5151db3f77e7847337000000',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
       expires: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 2000),
       maxAge: 60 * 2000
    }
}));
```

Thanks @robertklep and @Paul